# Using SoupStrainer to parse selectively

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrape

Im trying to parse a list of video game titles from a shopping site. however as the item list is all stored inside a tag .

[This](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Improving%20Performance%20by%20Parsing%20Only%20Part%20of%20the%20Document) section of the documentation supposedly explains how to parse only part of the document but i cant work it out. my code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re

url = "Some Shopping Site"
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for a in soup.findAll('a',{'title':re.compile('.+') }):
    print a.string
```

at present is prints the string inside any  tag that has a not empty title reference. but it is also priting the items in the side bar that are the "specials". if i can only take the product list div, i will kill 2 birds with one stone.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Oh boy am i silly, i was searching for tags with atribute id = products, but it should have been product_list

heres the finaly code if anyone comes searching.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import urllib
import re


start = time.clock()
url = "http://someplace.com"
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
product = SoupStrainer('div',{'id': 'products_list'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,parseOnlyThese=product)
for a in soup.findAll('a',{'title':re.compile('.+') }):
      print a.string
```

Comment: In bs4, it is now `parse_only=`

Answer (score 0):

Try searching first for the product list `div` and then for the `a` tags with title:

```
product = soup.find('div',{'id': 'products'})
for a in product.findAll('a',{'title': re.compile('.+') }):
   print a.string
```

Comment: tried that but it gave this error:                                     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/start.py", line 11, in <module>
    for a in product.findAll('a',{'title':re.compile('.+') }):
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'findAll'

Comment: Try calling `soup.find` instead of `soup.findAll`.

Comment: not its giving me this, Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/src/start.py", line 13, in <module>
    for a in product.findAll('a',{'title':re.compile('.+') }):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'

Comment: ok i tried to implement the strainer and this is what i got, but it does print anything(sorry not sure how to do new lines in a comment)    url = "somelink"
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
product = SoupStrainer('div',{'id': 'products'})  
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,parseOnlyThese=product)

for a in soup.findAll('a',{'title':re.compile('.+') }):
 print a.string